# terraform: ec2 machine change does not trigged dns change

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-provider-cloudflare

I've got simple code for many EC2 machines setup. It does not update DNS record after machine is changed. I need to run it second time - only then DNS will be changed. What am I doing wrong?

```
resource "aws_instance" "ec2" {
  for_each          = var.instances

  ami               = each.value.ami
  instance_type     = each.value.type
  ebs_optimized     = true
}

resource "cloudflare_record" "web" {
  for_each = var.instances

  zone_id  = var.cf_zone_id
  name     = "${each.key}.${var.env}.aws.${var.domain}."
  value    = aws_instance.ec2[each.key].public_ip
  type     = "A"
  ttl      = 1

  depends_on = [
    aws_instance.ec2
  ]
}
```

Comment: *"It does not update DNS record after machine is changed"* - who changes the machine and why and in what way? And why do you expect terraform react to some outside change?

Comment: For example after changed instance type. In such case ec2 is rebooted and gets new public IP. It's not outside change, instance type comes from variable.

Comment: Does someone update the terraform variable, then rollout that change, terraform then calls the APIs to change the instance type but does not update the cloudflare_record?

Comment: That's exactly what happens. I can see in plan only update for ec2 instance. Need to apply and then with next apply cloudflare_record is being updated.

Answer (score 0):

So, one thing about Terraform is that it provisions your infrastructure, but whatever happens with your infrastructure between your latest apply and now won't be reflected by the Terraform state file. If there is indeed a change in your infrastructure, then you would see it in the next Terraform plan. There is nothing wrong with what you're doing, only that you might have understood Terraform wrongly. There is a neat concept called "Immutable Infrastructure". Read it up in Hashicorp's blog: https://www.hashicorp.com/resources/what-is-mutable-vs-immutable-infrastructure

Comment: I understand immutable paradigm, I mean in my post I change ec2 instance in code, not in AWS console or somewhere else. When changing variable - I can see the plan for ec2 instance update, but not for cloduflare_record.